# guild.icon & guild.iconURL() not working in embed thumbnail

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to set guild icon as the thumbnail of `embed` but neither `guild.icon` nor `guild.iconURL()` work

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.channel.name === 'verify') {
        if(message.content === '!verify') {
            message.delete()
            let dm = message.author;
            let server = message.guild.name;
            let servericon = message.guild.iconURL();
            console.log(servericon)

            let attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(this.choose , 'chosen.png')

            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**Welcome to ${server}**\n\nCaptcha`)
            .setDescription("Please complete the captcha given below to gain access to the server.\n**Note:** This is case sensitive")
            .setAuthor('Mr.Verifier', "https://i.ibb.co/nckjDjG/hmm.png")
            .setThumbnail(servericon)
            .addField(
                { name: '**Why all this?**', value: 'This is to protect the servers from\nmalicious raids of automated bots'}
            )
            .setImage(`attachment://chosen.png`)


            dm.send(embed)

        }else{
        message.delete();
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: You said the thumbnail doesn't show up but you didn't paste the code for `servericon`, you need to show what you've tried.

Comment: sorry.by mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`guild.iconURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=iconURL).

Comment: it says null in console at that also.

Comment: is this embed in the guildMemberAdd event?

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: nvm. I fixed it. It was my mistake.